# Como inserir uma quebra de linha a cada 79 caracteres?

Tags: notepad++

Estou usando o Notepad++ e preciso encontrar uma forma (uma macro talvez) para inserir uma quebra de linha a cada 79 caracteres.
Uma observação importante é que a quebra de linha no final de cada 79 caracteres não pode ser feito após um espaço em branco e no inicio da outra linha não pode começar com espaço em branco.

Comment: Será que um find/replace com uma regex não funciona? Teste essa regex: `(.{79})` e dei replace por `$1\n` e funcionou. Fiz esse teste no **Sublime Text**, mas acho que é parecido.

Comment: @Wakim, testei no notepad++ 6.5.1 e funcinou coloca como resposta :).